# Print command isn't working in my program, all other commands seem to work

Tags: python

I made this code for the following activity:

Tickets are sold for a concert at $20 each, if 10
tickets are bought then discount is 10%, if 20 tickets
are sold the discount is 20%. No more than 25 tickets
can be bought in a single transaction. Print the cost
of buying a given number of tickets.

The code seems to be working fine, except for the 
"if (tickets > 25):
         print("only 25 tickets/transaction")"
All the other print commands print fine, except for this, where nothing appears in the shell if i enter a value higher than 25. Tried a couple different things in the code, but it doesn't seem to fix it, any ideas?

```
ticketsprice=0
tickets=0
tickets=float(input("enter number of tickets:"))
ticketsprice=(20*tickets)
ticketsprice10disc=(int(ticketsprice)-(ticketsprice/10))
ticketsprice20disc=(int(ticketsprice)-((ticketsprice/10)*2))
while (tickets<25):
    print("total price is %0.2f" %ticketsprice)

    if (tickets > 25):
     print("only 25 tickets/transaction")

    if (tickets == 10):
         print("discounted price is %0.2f" %ticketsprice10disc)

    if (tickets == 20):
        print("discounted price is %0.2f" %ticketsprice20disc)
    break
```

Comment: why dont you do `ticketsprice*0.9` for 10% discount and `ticketsprice*0.8` for 20%?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (tickets<25):
```

This loop will not execute if `tickets` is greater than or equal to 25. Your first conditional is not reachable in that case.

I'm not sure why this loop is here to begin with, since you `break` unconditionally at the end of it, so it will never execute more than once. I suggest deleting the `while` and the `break`, and de-indenting its contents.

You might be thinking "but what I *actually* want to do is to ask the user to enter the number of tickets again, if they initially enter a value that's too high. How can I do that without a while loop?". In that case, you should keep the while loop, but move the `input()` call within the loop body. Use `continue` to return to the top of the loop in the case of invalid input.

```
while True:
    tickets=float(input("enter number of tickets:"))
    ticketsprice=(20*tickets)
    print("total price is %0.2f" %ticketsprice)

    if (tickets > 25):
        print("only 25 tickets/transaction")
        continue
    break

if (tickets == 10):
    ticketsprice10disc=(int(ticketsprice)-(ticketsprice/10))
    print("discounted price is %0.2f" %ticketsprice10disc)

if (tickets == 20):
    ticketsprice20disc=(int(ticketsprice)-((ticketsprice/10)*2))
    print("discounted price is %0.2f" %ticketsprice20disc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. Your `while (tickets <25)` loop will not allow the `if(tickets>25)` statement to ever trigger.
2. The print statements' indent is not correct. This may have happened while copy-pasting but still a bug.
3. Your `break` statement is positioned a bit oddly. Currently the loop will break after one iteration everytime, no matter what the value of `tickets` is. Is this what you wanted?